# Regular expression for wrapping every word in span tag on word boundaries in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to wrap every word of a string in a `<span>` tag, without breaking any existing html tags and without including any punctuation marks.

For example the following string:

`This... is, an. example! <em>string</em>?!`

should be wrapped as:

```
<span>This</span>... <span>is</span>, <span>an</span>. <span>example</span>! 
<span><em>string</em></span>?!
```

Ideally, I just need to wrap the words and nothing else.

Except for apostrophes, they should be wrapped, too.

`it's` => `<span>it's</span>`

`give 'em` => `<span>give</span> <span>'em</span>`

`teachers'` => `<span>teachers'</span>`

Right now I'm using a very simple regular expression:

```
str.replace(/([^\s<>]+)(?:(?=\s)|$)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

I found it somewhere here on stackoverflow. But it only wraps every word on white spaces and wraps punctuation marks too, which is undesirable in my case.

I know I should be ashamed for being so lousy at regular expressions.

Can someone please help me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
var str = "This string... it's, an. example! <em>string</em>?!";
str.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9'<>/]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');

// "<span>This</span> <span>string</span>... <span>it's</span>, <span>an</span>. <span>example</span>! <span><em>string</em></span>?!"
```

Comment: It seems to work and it's simpler than I thought it would be. I really have to learn regexps. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by nested tags? I tried it on `<strong><em>word</em></strong>` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: You're very welcome, @wunderbox! Also, no reason to be ashamed of not knowing Regexes, I'm barely starting to understand them, also.

Answer (score 1):

I played around and got this to work :

```
String toMarkUp = "Each word needs a strong tag around it.  I really want to wrap each and every word";

String markedUp = toMarkUp.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\b","<span>$1</span>");
```

The regex is capturing every word with 1 or more characters (\w+) surrounded by word boundaries, and using forward lookup group to reference it in the replacement with a $1, 1 being the first capture group in the regex.

Output :

```
<span>Each</span> <span>word</span> <span>needs</span> <span>a</span> <span>strong</span> <span>tag</span> <span>around</span> <span>it</span>.  <span>I</span> <span>really</span> <span>want</span> <span>to</span> <span>emphasize</span> <span>each</span> <span>and</span> <span>every</span> <span>word</span>
```