# How to blur every occurrence of a substring in a <p>

Tags: javascript, html, angular, replace, substring

I am writing a program in Angular which displays short texts. In these texts I want to blur a certain substring, EACH time it occurs.

E.g. Tomorrow I will have to go to London. Tomorrow is the day it will happen. My only hope is tomorrow.

Here I would want to blur the text 'tomorrow', three times.
Sometimes the substring occurs once, sometimes twice, ... or five times.

A tap or click on the words or on the paragraph UNBLURS them.

I did it with an indexOf function, put the substring into a span with a different class and an ngStyle attribute. But this does it only for the first occurrence of the substring.

```
  const position = quoteL.indexOf(titleL);

  if (position > -1) { // if the substr appears in the quote -> chop up the string and blur it
    this.p1= quote?.substring(0, position);
    this.p2= quote?.substring(position, position + title.length);      
    this.p3= quote?.substring(position+title.length, quote.length);
} else {
    this.p1 = this.lyrics;
    this.p2="";
    this.p3=""
}
```

`

Comment: Show us your attempt as a [mre]

Comment: You may find it easier to use a regular expression to find and replace all instances of the word(s).

Answer (score 2):

My realisation with regular expression. Example on pure JS.

```
.highlighted {
  opacity: .3;
}

<p id="text">Tomorrow I will have to go to London. Tomorrow is the day it will happen. My only hope is tomorrow.</p>
<button onclick="highlightQueryStr('Tomorrow')">highlightQuery</button>
    
<script>
  function highlightQueryStr(query) {
    const textEl = document.querySelector("#text");
    const reg = new RegExp(query,"gi");
    textEl.innerHTML = textEl.innerHTML.replace(reg, `<span 
    class="highlighted">${query}</span>`);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is amazing/ simple result. I will have to look into RegExp. Didn't know it. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this answer to wrap every word in span.

[Regular expression for wrapping every word in span tag on word boundaries in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142192/regular-expression-for-wrapping-every-word-in-span-tag-on-word-boundaries-in-jav)

Then I would change the span to have an ngClass or similar to see if the innerText or innerHTML is equal to the word being blurred.

If you had a stackblitz which a minimal reproducible example I could be more specific.....

UPDATE BASED ON YOUR ANSWER BELOW

This is a good start. In order to turn this into a stackblitz:

1. visit stackblitz.com
2. scroll down the main page and select "Javascript blank project"
3. You could then place your CSS and HTML in the correct files and your result will [be something like this link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wrwfpp?file=index.js,style.css,index.html)

So I see what you are trying to do, but the approach is not quite on point. Later today, I will work on updating what is now a minimum reproduction of your issue with a potential solution.

Comment: I'll look into it.
Sometimes the text-to-be-blurred consists of a few words.

Comment: Thanks! For me the proposal from Leonid is great/ will work for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I make a directive and a pipe to transform an .html in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74561680/i-have-data-in-angular-thats-coming-from-the-backend-this-data-holds-a/74567202#74567202)

It's "easy" make that the "elements" are clicked adding as listen "click". As you have a directive use a `@Ouput` to emit the click event

```
@Output() click:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>() //define the EventEmitter

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML != this.oldValue) {
      ...
      this.renderer.listen(this.div,'click',(event)=>{
        this.click.emit(event)
      })
    }
  }
```

Now, in parent we can listen the event. Case the target was a `strong` tag we add a class no-blur

```
  click(event)
  {
    if (event.target.tagName=="STRONG")
      event.target.classList.add('no-blur');
  }
```

Of course the .css has changed

```
.highlight strong {
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
  filter: blur(.3rem);
}
.highlight strong.no-blur {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: normal;
  filter: none;
}
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c1qsbj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight.directive.ts)